Trapped in a Room
You are in a room with a table. On the table are 35 tiny holes. Now each hole has a number or letter on it. There are holes with a number range from 1 to 9, and there are also ones with letters from A to Z and none of the numbers or letters repeat. You are also given 3 pegs in an envelope with a letter. The letter says "For your challenge, you must stay sharp to interpret this or stay stuck forever.” That's it, nothing else. You have no resources or food. You understand that you have to solve the riddle or you will die. What do you do to get out?

Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!  If someone else created this puzzle, please let us know where you got it from.

Not sure if rot13(guvf vf n pbahaqehz? Vs guvf ebbz unf n qbbe, V bcra gur qbbe naq fgrc bhg.) or maybe not?

rot13(Gur jbeq "funec" zhfg or fvtavsvpnag.)

I suspect it's something like https://www.reddit.com/r/riddles/comments/4ylgi0/comment/d6omol6/

I made this riddle by myself. Please re-open this.

I think this is one of those riddles where the answer the asker expects fits the clues, but so do lots of other things. There are no clues that would rule out simple answers like

 put one peg in the hole marked O, another in the U, and the third in the T. You have now spelled (or got) OUT, as desired.

It's true that

this doesn't use the  "stay sharp" beyond the end of the peg needing to be sharp to go in the hole.

I think that's ok.

The OP's intended answer (which they self-deleted) also doesn't use "stay sharp"

Nice try. You’re on the right path, but not quite there.

There is nothing in the question that makes this answer (or many others) wrong. That's why it's closed. The question needs to make it clear why one answer, and only that one answer, is right

If I think of stay sharp as a musical clue.

 Then staying sharp means staying in key which is also an implement to unlock a door or window. So place the pegs in K E Y.


So close. Try again!
